# ¿Como mostrar todos los datos de una tabla en la terminal de python?

Tags: python, búsqueda-monte-carlo

Hola a todos soy nuevo aquí, creé este código con ChatGPT sobre una Simulación Montecarlo en Python y da como resultado una lista con los resultados de cada simulación y un resumen final de datos. Mi problema es que al querer copiar y pegar la tabla para el excel, empieza desde la simulacion 1502 hasta 2500 (que fue el valor final que puse) y no desde la simulacion 1 hasta la 2500. Como puedo hacer para que me muestre la tabla completa y yo asi poder copiar y pegar?? Gracias

```
import random

def SimulacionMontecarloTradingRiesgoVariable():
    saldoInicial = float(input("Ingrese el saldo inicial: "))
    riesgoPorOperacion = float(input("Ingrese el riesgo por operación inicial (como decimal, ej: 0.01 para 1%): "))
    riesgoMaximo = float(input("Ingrese el riesgo máximo por operación (como decimal, ej: 0.02 para 2%): "))
    riesgoMinimo = float(input("Ingrese el riesgo mínimo por operación (como decimal, ej: 0.001 para 0.1%): "))
    winrate = float(input("Ingrese el winrate (porcentaje de operaciones ganadoras, ej: 70 para 70%): "))
    riesgoBeneficio = float(input("Ingrese la tasa de riesgo/beneficio: "))
    aumentoRiesgo = float(input("Ingrese el aumento de riesgo por ganancia (como decimal, ej: 0.2 para 20%): "))
    reduccionRiesgo = float(input("Ingrese la reducción de riesgo por pérdida (como decimal, ej: 0.1 para 10%): "))
    numOperaciones = int(input("Ingrese el número de operaciones por simulación: "))
    numSimulaciones = int(input("Ingrese el número de simulaciones: "))

    # Inicialización de variables
    resultados = []
    maximoSaldo = 0
    minimoSaldo = 0

    for simulacion in range(1, numSimulaciones + 1):
        saldoFinal = saldoInicial
        operacionesGanadas = 0
        operacionesPerdidas = 0
        mayorGananciaSeguida = 0
        mayorPerdidaSeguida = 0
        porcentajeGananciaSeguida = 0
        porcentajePerdidaSeguida = 0
        maxGanadasSimulacion = 0
        maxPerdidasSimulacion = 0
        maxSaldoFlotante = saldoInicial
        minSaldoFlotante = saldoInicial
        rachaGanadas = 0  # Inicializa la variable rachaGanadas a 0
        rachaPerdidas = 0  # Inicializa la variable rachaPerdidas a 0

        for operacion in range(1, numOperaciones + 1):
            if random.uniform(0, 100) <= winrate:
                ganancia = riesgoPorOperacion * riesgoBeneficio
                saldoFinal = saldoFinal + ganancia * saldoInicial
                operacionesGanadas = operacionesGanadas + 1
                riesgoPorOperacion = riesgoPorOperacion * (1 + aumentoRiesgo)
                if riesgoPorOperacion > riesgoMaximo:
                    riesgoPorOperacion = riesgoMaximo
                porcentajeGananciaSeguida = porcentajeGananciaSeguida + ((riesgoPorOperacion * riesgoBeneficio) * 100)
                porcentajePerdidaSeguida = 0
                rachaGanadas = rachaGanadas + 1
                if rachaGanadas > maxGanadasSimulacion:
                    maxGanadasSimulacion = rachaGanadas
            else:
                perdida = -riesgoPorOperacion
                saldoFinal = saldoFinal + perdida * saldoInicial
                operacionesPerdidas = operacionesPerdidas + 1
                riesgoPorOperacion = riesgoPorOperacion * (1 - reduccionRiesgo)
                if riesgoPorOperacion < riesgoMinimo:
                    riesgoPorOperacion = riesgoMinimo
                porcentajePerdidaSeguida = porcentajePerdidaSeguida + (riesgoPorOperacion * 100)
                porcentajeGananciaSeguida = 0
                rachaGanadas = 0
                rachaPerdidas = rachaPerdidas + 1
                if rachaPerdidas > maxPerdidasSimulacion:
                    maxPerdidasSimulacion = rachaPerdidas

            if porcentajeGananciaSeguida > mayorGananciaSeguida:
                mayorGananciaSeguida = porcentajeGananciaSeguida
            if porcentajePerdidaSeguida > mayorPerdidaSeguida:
                mayorPerdidaSeguida = porcentajePerdidaSeguida

            if saldoFinal > maxSaldoFlotante:
                maxSaldoFlotante = saldoFinal
            if saldoFinal < minSaldoFlotante:
                minSaldoFlotante = saldoFinal

            if simulacion == 1:
                maximoSaldo = saldoFinal
                minimoSaldo = saldoFinal
            else:
                if saldoFinal > maximoSaldo:
                    maximoSaldo = saldoFinal
                if saldoFinal < minimoSaldo:
                    minimoSaldo = saldoFinal

        escenario = (saldoFinal - saldoInicial) / saldoInicial * 100
        ecu_Ganancia = round((escenario / numOperaciones) * 1000) / 1000
        resultados.append([
            simulacion, round(saldoFinal, 2), round(escenario, 2), operacionesGanadas, operacionesPerdidas,
            round(mayorGananciaSeguida, 2), round(mayorPerdidaSeguida, 3), ecu_Ganancia,
            round(((saldoFinal - saldoInicial) / numOperaciones) * 10) / 10, maxGanadasSimulacion,
            maxPerdidasSimulacion, round(maxSaldoFlotante, 2), round(minSaldoFlotante, 2)])

    # Imprimir resultados en forma de tabla
    print("Simulación Montecarlo de Trading con Riesgo Variable")
    print(
        "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("| N° | Saldo Final | Rendimiento (%) | TP | SL | Mayor % Ganancia | Mayor % Drawdown | Ecuación de Ganancia | Saldo por Operación | Mayor Ganadas | Mayor Perdidas | Max Saldo Flotante | Min Saldo Flotante |")
    print(
        "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    for row in resultados:
        print("|", row[0], "|", row[1], "|", row[2], "% |", row[3], "|", row[4], "|", row[5], "% |", row[6], "% |", row[7], "|",
              row[8], "|", row[9], "|", row[10], "|", row[11], "|", row[12], "|")

    totalVictorias = sum(row[3] for row in resultados)
    totalDerrotas = sum(row[4] for row in resultados)
    maxRachaGanadas = max(row[9] for row in resultados)
    maxRachaPerdidas = max(row[10] for row in resultados)

    print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("Resumen de simulación:")
    print("Promedio de saldo conseguido:", round(sum(row[1] for row in resultados) / numSimulaciones, 2),
          "-- Ecuación mediana rendimiento:", round(sum(row[2] for row in resultados) / numSimulaciones, 3))
    print("Mayor saldo flotante:", round(maximoSaldo, 2),
          "que del Saldo Inicial representa ganancia de:", round(((maximoSaldo - saldoInicial) * 100 / saldoInicial), 2), "%")
    print("Menor saldo flotante:", round(minimoSaldo, 2),
          "que del Saldo Inicial representa pérdida de:", round(((minimoSaldo - saldoInicial) * 100 / saldoInicial), 2), "%")
    print("Mayor saldo final en una simulación:", round(max(row[1] for row in resultados), 2))
    print("Menor saldo final en una simulación:", round(min(row[1] for row in resultados), 2))
    print("Total de operaciones ganadas:", totalVictorias)
    print("Total de operaciones perdidas:", totalDerrotas)
    print("Mayor cantidad de operaciones ganadas seguidas en una simulación:", maxRachaGanadas)
    print("Mayor cantidad de operaciones perdidas seguidas en una simulación:", maxRachaPerdidas)
    print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

SimulacionMontecarloTradingRiesgoVariable()
```

Comment: En vez de imprimir la salida por pantalla, envíala a un archivo, incluso puedes redirigir la salida de tu script, algo como esto: `python tu_script.py > archivo.txt`

Comment: Ten en cuenta que el terminal tiene un límite de buffer aprox. 1000 recomiendo como dijo @PatricioMoracho, también hay la opción de integrarlo al código, pero la más rápida es la que dijo él.

Comment: Gracias, ahí pude